# How to list "Visiting Student" on my CV?

Tags: graduate-admissions, cv

As a soon-to-graduate undergraduate student that is on his hunt for a M.Sc. program, I am making sure my CV is up to date.

I would like to highlight the fact that I have attended a nearby university as a "visiting student" and have successfully completed two courses at this institution while still holding a full time student (normal course load) status at my home institution. I had one of the courses credited at my home institution and did not bother with the second. This second course was simply for my own interest and would not have helped me achieve any graduation requirements at my home institution.

My question is two fold:

1. Is this fact worth highlighting in my CV, considering the limited (and precious) real-estate in the two page CV format?
2. If so, what would be the best way to present it?

Possible formats that I have considered (should I mention it):

1.

> Education
>
> XXXX - YYYY: University of Somewhere, B.Sc. (Major in interesting subject, minor in cool subject)
>
> Also completed heavy coursework in awesome subject. Visiting student to University of Elsewhere during academic year ZZZZ - ZZZZ + 1

2.

> Education
>
> XXXX - YYYY: University of Somewhere, B.Sc. (Major in interesting subject, minor in cool subject)
>
> Also completed heavy coursework in awesome subject.
>
> ZZZZ - ZZZZ + 1: University of Elsewhere, Visiting Student
>
> Completed N credits: SCI101 and ART102

In my (naive) opinion, I would believe that this sort of "academic diversity" would be favourably viewed by someone looking at my CV.

Some would also say that, in my case, University of Elsewhere has a better reputation and name recognition then my home institution. Should this be considered as a valid reason to give it more space on my CV?

Comment: Seems very similar to this question: http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/5961/is-it-acceptable-practice-to-list-solitary-courses-on-an-academic-cv?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

I have my visiting student experiences listed individually as if they were education segments or professional appointments. I just make sure that my current appointment/school is listed first. I use the format:

```
XXXX - present: University of Somewhere, B.Sc. (Major in interesting subject, minor in cool subject)
  Cool blabla I did here. Credits earned, etc.

ZZZZ - ZZZZ: University of Elsewhere, Visiting Student
  Cool blabla I did there. Credits earned, etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

If the two courses strengthen the picture of you in the target academic area, and they fit into your two-page format, then you can include them.  In other words, if you're having space problems, or if they're not specifically relevant, just leave them out.

To answer the format question -- let the degrees, course names and institution names speak for themselves.  Your CV will be more elegant that way, and you'll save space.

> **Education**
>
> (each item will be listed as follows -- and each item will be all on one line, wrapping if needed)
>
> month, year (of graduation with degree, or of course completion)
>
> name of degree and institution (optional level of distinction) OR name
>   of individual course(s) and name of institution