# How to list exchange studies in CV?

Tags: ethics, cv, bachelor

Imagine you studied 6 semesters (fall 2017 to fall 2020) at a university and 1 semester (fall 2020 to spring 2021) at a second university in order to obtain your bachelors degree. Is it fine to list it in your CV like

- 2017-2020 ETH, Swiss Federal Institute of Technology Zurich, Bachelors Degree
- 2020-2021 KTH, Royal Institute of Technology Stockholm, Bachelors Degree

even though one technically only received a degree from the first university and wrote the thesis for this degree at the second university?

Comment: Related: https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/51685/68109

Comment: @Buffy Concerning your last comment: I removed the last sentence as this was misleading and unncecessary. Thank you for your answer, I didn't downvote it.

Comment: I tried to make it a bit more complete, also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems simple enough to be clear as your double bullets aren't, implying two degrees.

> Bachelors Degree: ETHZ, 2021 (with studies at ETHZ (2017 - 2020) with thesis work at RITS (2020 - 2021) as a visitor

It is clear when the single degree was given, and by which university as well as some indication that some study was undertaken at RITS.

Other variations work, of course.